# Symfony2 - EntityNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a `Stats` entity that is related to a `Journey` entity through a `ManyToOne` association.

```
id:
    index:
        type: integer

fields:
        idJourney:
        type: string
// data fields...
manyToOne:
    journey:
        targetEntity: Journey
        joinColumn:
            name: idJourney
            referencedColumnName: idJourney
```

The `Journey` is related to the `Station` entity through two `ManyToOne` association: one for the first `Station` of the `Journey`, one for the last.

```
id:
    idjourney:
        type: string
    fields:
        idFirstStation:
            type: string
        idLastStation:
            type: string
    // other info fields
    manyToOne:
        firstStation:
            targetEntity: Station
            joinColumn:
                name: idFirstStation
                referencedColumnName: idStation
        lastStation:
            targetEntity: Station
            joinColumn:
                name: idLastStation
                referencedColumnName: idStation
```

Finally, the `Station` entity :

```
id:
    idStation:
        type: string
fields:   
    name:
        type: string
// other station info
```

I retrieve a collection of `Stats` objects with all related sub-objects via a custom Repository method which works fine.

```
$statCollection = $statsRepository->getStatsByDateAndArea($date, $area);

//This retrieves the expected data
$statCollection[0]->getJourney()->getFirstStation()->getName();
```

However, iterating through the collection with a `foreach` loop doesn't work:

```
foreach($statCollection as $stat) {
    $journey = $stat->getJourney(); // works fine
    $firstStationId = $journey->getFirstStationId(); // works too
    $firstStation = $journey->getFirstStation(); // still works, but returns a Proxies\AcmeAppPathWhateverBundleEntityStationProxy object instead of a AcmeAppPathWhateverBundleEntityStation, but this should be transparent (as per Doctrine documentation)
    $firstStationName = $firstStation->getName(); // throws an EntityNotFoundException
}
```

Any idea what's going on ? Should I force Doctrine to fetch all sub entities ?

**EDIT**
The error message is fairly laconic :

```
EntityNotFoundException: Entity was not found.
```

Not very helpful...

Comment: Can you give more details about the exception thrown (message, etc...)?

Comment: Edited question with full Error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up querying explicitly for the full set of sub-entities in my custom repository method...

I changed this query :

```
    ->select('stats')
    ->leftJoin('stats.journey', 'j')
    ->leftJoin('j.firstStation', 'fs')
    ->leftJoin('j.lastStation', 'ls')
```

to :

```
    ->select('stats, j, fs, ls')
    ->leftJoin('stats.journey', 'j')
    ->leftJoin('j.firstStation', 'fs')
    ->leftJoin('j.lastStation', 'ls')
```

I guess Doctrine's use of Proxy objects are not all that transparent...