# Symfony2 Doctrine manyToOne EntityNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-one

I've just started learning Symfony but have run in to something I can't figure out how to solve.

I have a database table of records which may or may not be linked to a user. One user could have many records but a record doesn't have to be associated to a user

I've used doctrine with yml to create a manyToOne relationship between the 2 tables

```
user:
        targetEntity: User
        mappedBy: records
        joinColumn:
            name: user_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

This works absolutely fine when the record has a user associated with it

The problem occurs when the user_id against the record is set to 0

Symfony loads it as a user object, but when I try to do

```
{{ record.user.name }}
```

In my twig template while looping through each record, I get an EntityNotFoundException being thrown

I've tried to do different things like

```
{% if record.user is null %}
```

With no luck

The only similar question I've been able to find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180244/symfony2-entitynotfoundexception)

Which I know would solve my issue, but as I'm learning Symfony and Doctrine I want to know if writing the SQL myself is my only option or if there is something I'm missing to make this work

I guess I could also create a user with the id of 0 but I would like to learn how this should be done rather than doing something dirty like that

My model does the following to load the records

```
$repository = $this->doctrine->getRepository('SiteBundle:Records');
$records = $repository->findAll();
```

This is then passed to my twig template which loops through them for output

Thanks in advance for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17338761/3574819

Instead of setting the `user_id` of records that don't have a user to `0`, set the `user_id` to `null`.

Then you can check whether the `user` object is null (or perhaps you need to use `defined`) before accessing its properties.

```
{% if records.user is not null %}
  {{ records.user.name }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't solve my issue. I've tried {% if record.user is defined %} and I've also tried first doing {% set user = record.user %} and then checking user but both still end up with the EntityNotFoundException

Comment: Thanks, that worked. A little annoying doctrine doesn't seem to handle 0's with it's relationship mapping but at least I know now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
                {% if records.user is not empty %}
                   {{ records.user.name }}
                 {% endif %}
```

In stead of "null" , "empty" property woks fine here ..